# Swift - Parse results always empty now but were NOT before? Can still post object but not get with query?

Tags: ios, swift, heroku, parse-platform

I am incredibly upset and need some guidance. I presently have a Swift app in iOS running off Parse via Heroku (so its not dying and thats not the reason).

Up until yesterday, everything has gone well. I have been able to read and write to my database like this and it has all worked fine:

```
let ideaPost = PFObject(className: "ideaPosts")
                ideaPost["mood"] = moodField.text
                ideaPost["ideaText"] = ideaTextField.text
                ideaPost.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    print("Object has been saved.")
```

Here is my database as proof:

[image]

I created all those objects today. Up until today I have been accurately able to query and receive objects like this:

```
ParseHelper.searchPosts(mood!, completionBlock: handleIdea)
```

and

```
   static func searchPosts(searchText: String, completionBlock: PFQueryArrayResultBlock) -> PFQuery {
        /*
         NOTE: We are using a Regex to allow for a case insensitive compare of usernames.
         Regex can be slow on large datasets. For large amount of data it's better to store
         lowercased username in a separate column and perform a regular string compare.
         */

//        let query = PFQuery(className: "ideaPosts").whereKey(("mood"),
//                                                             matchesRegex: searchText, modifiers: "i")

        let query = PFQuery(className: "ideaPosts").whereKey(("mood").lowercaseString,
                                                             equalTo: searchText.lowercaseString)

        query.orderByAscending("createdAt")

        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock(completionBlock)


        return query
    }
```

As you can see, Im referencing the right class and right fields. To my knowledge (I was moving fast last night and must have touched something accidentally) I haven't changed a bit of code. My project is in ruins because of this.

Why is this happening? Why are my results always empty? I output the returned results PFObject as it came back as an empty optional.

The only 2 things I can think that I have changed is 1. I renamed my project (thus Xcode went a renamed all my targets, yet I have no build errors or anything) And earlier I cleaned out (deleted some rows) in my table.

I also added a new database/set of servers to my account But again this shouldn't affect anything I don't think. I am desperate. What is going wrong here?

I have cleaned my build and everything even.

Comment: Hi, in your query you specify where mood equalTo:searchText.lowercaseString but if i look at the results that you attached under "mood" column i don't see any lowercase strings .. i think you can just remove the lowercaseString and do only equalTo:searchText.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search code will generate empty results if it tries to match lowercase `searchText` with mixed case data in the mood attribute (which it looks to be).

```
.whereKey(("mood").lowercaseString, equalTo:searchText.lowercaseString)
```

The first operand names the column which is being compared, that is `"mood"`, and it's worth noting that `("mood").lowercaseString == "mood"`

The regex looks more promising.  Is it possible commenting that out was a change you made recently?

Other than regex, the only way case-insensitive match the mood column is to keep another column like `mood_i` where the data is forced to lowercase, and search that.  A common practice for initializing such a column is on `afterSave`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I must have switched out those two queries. Still curious though- why doesn't the first one work if they're both lowercase?

Comment: Happy to help. On the first one, they aren't both lower case. That first param is the column *name*, not it's value. That code makes the word "mood" lower case, which it already is.